# What happens? - ACS & Push and Node.ACS deactivation On October 3, 2016

Tags: appcelerator

> 'Titanium community analytics, ACS & Push and Node.ACS
>   deactivation
>
> On October 3, 2016, Appcelerator will shut down its community
>   analytics, ACS & Push, and Node.ACS servers.'

Does anyone have any more information on this?

We have a lot of client applications still using ACS api.cloud.appcelerator.com to generate push tokens for our applications. We manage our own push services but still use the cloud libraries to generate push notifications.

What exactly is happening on October 3?

Is api.cloud.appcelerator.com closing completely? How does this affect exist applications in the store? Will they crash if they can not reach api.cloud.appcelerator.com?

Comment: I agree it's confusing, but this seems like a question for Appcelerator.

Comment: How do you contact appcelerator other than here? I used the contact form a few times on there site and never got a reply.